# How do I disable SSLv3 in tomcat?

Tags: security, ssl, tomcat7

Please provide the fix for [How do I patch/workaround SSLv3 POODLE vulnerability (CVE­-2014­-3566)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/537196/how-do-i-patch-workaround-sslv3-poodle-vulnerability-cve-2014-3566?) for Tomcat.

I have tried following below link, however it does not help: [tomcat-users mailing list archives](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/tomcat-users/201303.mbox/%3C13A085B2E018374C813676301AED0EE412D87457C3@BLR0EXC00.us.sonicwall.com%3E)

Comment: Note that the real answer here will depend on the version of Tomcat: Tomcat 6 & Tomcat 7 have different configuration directives; and Tomcat 6 added some specific SSL directives somewhere around 6.0.32. The configuration directives depend on if you are using JSSE verses  APR/Native connectors. The supported of TLS specified in the parameters will depend on your Java version.

Comment: Also see ServerFault: http://serverfault.com/questions/637649/how-do-i-disable-sslv3-support-in-apache-tomcat

Answer (score 7):

Add the below string to server.xml connecter

```
sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2"
```

and then remove

```
sslProtocols="TLS"
```

check on

http://poodlebleed.com/

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/

Comment: This isn't working for us with Tomcat6.

Comment: These are Tomcat 7 instructions.  For 6, go to this page and search for "TLS": http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html or check out Marco Polo's answer below.

Comment: Hmm, that Tomcat 6 doc says it supports `sslEnabledProtocols` and there is no mention on that page of `sslProtocols`. Is that an inaccuracy in the Tomcat docs or is it JVM dependent?

Comment: @Bradley Tomcat 6 changed these directives somewhere after Tomcat 6.0.36. See our answer on ServerFault at http://serverfault.com/a/637666/36178

Answer (score 2):

[All more modern browsers of note work with at least TLS1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Web_browsers).  There are no safe SSL protocols any more, which means no more IE6 access to secure web sites.

[Test your server for this vulnerability with nmap](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Weak_SSL/TLS_Ciphers,_Insufficient_Transport_Layer_Protection_(OTG-CRYPST-001)#Example_3._Checking_for_Certificate_information.2C_Weak_Ciphers_and_SSLv2_via_nmap) in a few seconds:

```
nmap --script ssl-cert,ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 www.example.com
```

If ssl-enum-ciphers lists a "SSLv3:" section or any other SSL
sections, your server is vulnerable.

To patch this vulnerability on a Tomcat 7 web server, in the `server.xml` connector, remove

```
sslProtocols="TLS"
```

(or `sslProtocol="SSL"` or similar) and replace it with:

```
sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2"
```

Then restart tomcat and test again to verify that SSL is no longer accepted.  Thanks to Connor Relleen for the correct `sslEnabledProtocols` string.

Answer (score 2):

Using

```
sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2"
```

did not work for us. We had to use

```
sslProtocols="TLSv1, TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2"
```

and left out the `sslEnabledProtocols` altogether.

Comment: What version of Tomcat?

Comment: Tested and confirmed on tomcat 6.

Comment: Is that a typo? Did you mean `sslProtocol` (singular) instead of `sslProtocols` (plural)? The [Tomcat docs say `sslProtocol`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/http.html#SSL_Support), not `sslProtocols`.

Comment: Well, `sslProtocols` works for me as well on Tomcat 6. I find it strange that the documentation only mentions `sslProtocol` (no s).

Answer (score 0):

For Tomcat 6, in addition to the above, we also had to do the following:

In `server.xml` connector, add:

```
ciphers="TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"
```

Source: https://forums.openclinica.com/discussion/15696/firefox-39-new-ssl-cipher-security-setting-error-tomcat-6-fix