# Failure during ssl handshake while sending mail using openssl

Tags: command-line, email, openssl, smtp

I am trying to send mail from terminal using openssl by connecting to gmail's server using ssl on the port 465. Things are fine until i enter from address and authenticate. But when i enter RCPT TO, i get the following error.

```
RCPT TO: <abc@gmail.com>
RENEGOTIATING
139815845389984:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:SSL3_WRITE_BYTES:ssl handshake failure:s3_pkt.c:596:
```

I can guess out that the problem might be due to missing security certificates.
Can someone please help me solve the problem?

Comment: Could it have something to do with [POODLE](http://askubuntu.com/questions/537196/how-do-i-patch-workaround-sslv3-poodle-vulnerability-cve-2014-3566) and SSLv3?

Comment: @muru i am a newbie to smtp/ssl and so i am not that sure of what the problem is!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the `openssl s_client` program which is for testing purposes only. The capital `R` letter has a special meaning in `openssl s_client` (see `man s_client`), it triggers a renegotiation as you can see.

Solution: SMTP accepts lowercase commands too, so use lowercase `r` as in:

```
rcpt to: <some@example.com>
```

Alternative solution: use GnuTLS instead of OpenSSL as a SSL/TLS client:

```
gnutls-cli -p 465 smtp.gmail.com
```